# Removal of burned NFT from a collection I created in opensea

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, nft, opensea

Recently I have created a NFT collection of 100 individual NFT in Ethereum network, And then I have burned 5 NFT via burn function . After a while , when I looked into opensea collection page of mine its still showing me the 5 burned NFT .

I even tried to refresh the metadata but still burned NFT are visible in the opensea collection. I came through some opensea docs and they mentioned this "You can delete an item if you created it using OpenSea’s Shared Storefront '' but unfortunately I didn't use OpenSea’s Shared Storefront. Is there any way to delete the burned NFT from opensea collection.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. The solution only exists if you report it as a bug and send all the links. They will assist you to remove it.